# Best way to store bank account information of users?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, security, ruby-on-rails-4

What is the best way to safely store bank account information of users in a ruby on rails app?

I would like to store the information in a way in which admins can view the full bank info while still being encrypted in the database.

The point of this is so that I have a quick reference to their bank info in order to wire money to their bank accounts from my own bank website.

Is this a good idea?

Any ideas for doing this securely with minimum liability?

Thanks

Comment: Do a web search on PCI compliance. It's not simply a technical issue, but rather, one of best practices and (expensive) certification by a regulatory agency.

Comment: There is no secure way to do this. In case of breach, any encrypted data that your code can decrypt, attacker can decrypt. The only way to make the data secure is to make the server unbreakable; if you can't be sure to do this, you should not be storing bank data (ask-and-forget is annoying to users, but doesn't make you as vulnerable).

Comment: @MarsAtomic, I would not be storing credit cards which from my understanding is necessary for PCI compliance. I believe bank accounts don't fall under that?

Comment: The best way to store it is to not store it. The second best way to store it is to hire a security professional to make recommendation on how to do it properly. The way you deal with liability is by having an expert on call to sign off on any approach you use. This could destroy your company if you do it wrong, you'd be sued into oblivion.

Comment: Good point. I assumed you wanted payment card info, but you're literally after account info. While there's no centralized regulation (to my knowledge), the standards are no less stringent if you're approaching this issue in an ethical manner. There are companies that offer tokenization services for customer data, and it might be wise to go the third party route. Punting to a third party make the task technically and legally easier.

Comment: @MarsAtomic do you know of any good tokenization services? Thank you so much

Comment: I'm loathe to recommend a specific vendor, but here's a [PDF document](https://securosis.com/assets/library/reports/Securosis_Understanding_Tokenization_V.1_.0_.pdf) which can give you an overview. The document is from a vendor, but please don't construe this as an endorsement of their services.

Comment: @MarsAtomic thank you

Comment: @MarsAtomic, I took a look at the PDF document. Can you point me to where I can find actual tokenization services? I don't need to make payments with the service; I just need to be able to store bank account information securely and access it, similar to the person posting the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for something like this I like to use the [attr_encrypted gem](https://github.com/attr-encrypted/attr_encrypted)
this is really simple to use

1) add the attr_encrypted  to the Gemfile

```
gem "attr_encrypted"
```

2) now in your model you can do something like

```
class User
  attr_encrypted :bank_account_number, key: 'This is a key that is 256 bits!!'
end
```

3) now all you need to know is how to get the data out

```
  user = User.new
  user.bank_account_number = '123456789'
  user.bank_account_number # returns the unencrypted object ie. '123456789'
  user.encrypted_bank_account_number # returns the encrypted version of :bank_account_number
```

I hope that this helps 
Happy Hacking 
      user.save

Comment: How do you store the key though ? I assume it is bad practice to leave it in the model (since its usually versioned)

Comment: take a look at this gist on how i have it set up https://gist.github.com/mzaragoza/33fe2db30682071566325c72215efdcd I hope that it helps

Comment: Is this safe, PCI compliant? I am wondering because why are people always afraid to store banking information, even with this gem?